# Django URL Conf Returns Incorrect "Current URL"

Tags: django, django-urls, lighttpd

I have a django app that is mostly done, and the URLs work perfectly when I run it with the manage.py runserver command. However, I've recently tried to get it running via lighttpd, and many links have stopped working.

For example: http://mysite.com/races/32 should work, but instead throws this error message.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mysite.com/races/32
Using the URLconf defined in racetrack.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^create/$
^races/$
^races/(?P<race_id>\d+)/$
^races/(?P<race_id>\d+)/manage/$
^races/(?P<text>\w+)/$
^user/(?P<kol_id>\d+)/$
^$
^login/$
^logout/$
The current URL, 32, didn't match any of these.
```

The request URL is accurate, but the last line (which displays the current URL) is giving 32 instead of races/32 as expected.

Here is my urlconf:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('racetrack.races.views',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^create/$', 'create'),
    (r'^races/$', 'index'),
    (r'^races/(?P<race_id>\d+)/$', 'detail'),
    (r'^races/(?P<race_id>\d+)/manage/$', 'manage'),
    (r'^races/(?P<text>\w+)/$', 'index'),
    (r'^user/(?P<kol_id>\d+)/$', 'user'),
    # temporary for index page replace with welcome page
    (r'^$', 'index'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
    (r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'races/login.html'}),
    (r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the problem lies in the configuration of lighttpd.

Django is capable of "translating" "request urls" to "current urls" for the url checking, for example via the [django.root](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#basic-configuration) configuration for `mod_python`.

Comment: Which lighttpd configuration files should I include to help pinpoint the issue? I haven't been working on that side of things, but I do have access to it.